# how to pass dynamic query string in SEO url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this query string URL for detail page "detail.php?id=860&c=house&t=engineer". It will redirect to "detail/860/house/engineer" using rewrite rule.

sometimes I have to pass an extra parameter in detail page but rewrite doesn't accept those query strings.

This is rewrite rule in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ detail.php?id=$1&c=$2&t=$3 [L,NC]
```

if I'd add the fourth param is 'rb' I can add here easily but the fourth param will be 'rb' or 'rul' or whatever may be.

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use it something like this if you want to use 5th parameter, `detail/860/house/engineer/<dynamic param>/<your value>`

```
RewriteRule ^detail/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ detail.php?id=$1&c=$2&t=$3&$4=$5 [L,NC]
```